Dogleg Trust Region Method Fail
I'm implementing in Julia the Dogleg Trust Region Method.
I've got this:
function trust_dogleg(f::Function,xₖ,δ,δₖ,η;ϵ=10e-8,iter_max=1000000)
    iter=0
    gₖ=gradiente(f,xₖ)
    Bₖ=hessian(f,xₖ)
    while norm(gₖ)>ϵ && iter<iter_max
        m(t)=f(xₖ)+gₖ'*t+0.5*t'*Bₖ*t
        #Resuelvo 4.3 con Metodo Dogleg
        p_B=Bₖ\(-gₖ)
        p_U= -(((gₖ'*gₖ)/(gₖ'*Bₖ*gₖ))*gₖ)
        if norm(p_B) <= δₖ
            d=p_B
        elseif norm(p_U)>=δₖ
            τ=δₖ/norm(p_U)
            d=τ*p_U
        else
            #p=(p_U + (τ-1)*(p_B - p_U))'*(p_U + (τ-1)*(p_B - p_U))
            #a=norm(p_B-p_U)^2
            a=p_B'*p_B-2*p_B'*p_U+p_U'*p_U
            #b=2*(p_B-p_U)'*p_U
            b=2*p_B'*p_U-2*p_U'*p_U
            #c=norm(p_U)^2-δₖ^2
            c=p_U'*p_U-δₖ^2
            τ=resolvente(a,b,c)+1
            d=p_U + (τ - 1)*(p_B - p_U)
        end
        cero=zeros(length(d))
        #
        ρ=(f(xₖ)-f(xₖ+d))/(m(cero)-m(d))
        if ρ<1/4
            δₖ=(1/4)*δₖ
        else
            if ρ>3/4 && norm(d)==δₖ
                if 2*δₖ<δ
                    δₖ=2*δₖ
                else
                    δₖ=δ
                end
            #else δₖ=δₖ
            end
        if ρ>η
            xₖ=xₖ+d
            gₖ=gradiente(f,xₖ)
            Bₖ=hessian(f,xₖ)
        #else xₖ=xₖ
        end
        end
        iter=iter+1
    end
    return xₖ,iter
end

When I use this with this function:
function valle(v::Vector{Float64})
    x, y = v[1], v[2]
    return (x^2 + y^2) * exp(-((x^2 + y^2) / 20))
end

And call:
iniciodd_2=[2.0,1.0]
trust_dogleg(valle,iniciodd_2,1.5,1,0.2)

I noticed that the method is growing. And the key is that m(cero)-m(d) is negative (when it must be positive because d is the minimum in a region where there is the 0). On the first step, is calculating d with this block:
elseif norm(p_U)>=δₖ
            τ=δₖ/norm(p_U)
            d=τ*p_U

Also, I'm calculating the gradient with:
function gradiente(fun,x::Vector{Float64})
    nv = length(x)
    h = 0.00001

    xh1 = x.+h
    xh0 = x.-h
    hh  = xh1 - xh0  # 2h
    
    fderiv = zeros(nv)

    if nv == 1
        f1 = fun(xh1)
        f0 = fun(xh0)
        fderiv = (f1-f0)/(2*h)
    else
        for j=1:nv
            xx = copy(x)
            xx[j] = xh1[j]
            f1 = fun(xx)
            xx[j] = xh0[j]
            f0 = fun(xx)
            fderiv[j] = (f1-f0)/(2*h)
        end
    end
    
    return fderiv
end

And the Hessian with the Julia function. Any idea of where the algorithm is failing?
